# Selenium org.openqa.selenium.WebDriver is not accessable

Tags: java, eclipse, selenium, selenium-webdriver

I have used UFT for years and am transitioning back to Selenium. I have attempted to build a starting project with which to begin my learning, but I seem to be missing .jar files. However, I have included every .jar file that was downloaded with the files available on the selenium.dev/downloads page. The demos I have seen all show older versions of the seleniumhq page which I see no longer exists. Here is a screenshot of my eclipse window:

[image: Eclipse Error Image Here]

[image: Build Path Image Here]

I downloaded/installed the following:

Java SE 13.0.2

From https://selenium.dev/downloads/
-Selenium Server 3.141.59
-Selenium Client and WebDriver for Java 3.141.59
   --This was extracted to a folder and all lib and root jar files are listed

Also downloaded:
-Eclipse Version: 2019-12 (4.14.0)
-ChromeDriver
-EdgeDriver

I added the appropriate Environment Variables per the demo I was viewing (Path and JAVA_HOME) and loaded all the jar files that came with the selenium downloads into Eclipse. However, I still cannot get the error to go away. Any ideas?

Comment: Also added the selenium-java-3.141.59.zip download of jar files from the selenium.dev page. Even after adding those jar files, I still cannot get the error to go away.

Answer (score 1):

Okay, after working with the solution I found that deleting the module-info.java file resolved the issues listed above. I'm not sure why, but it did!